# Unveil lazy loading plugin error

Tags: jquery, jquery-lazyload

I'm trying to use the unveil plugin in my c# .net mvc project. I get this error.

jquery.unveil.js:13 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined

The jquery.unveil.js script file is in the Scripts folder. And below is my View.

```
<div class="images">
    <img...
    <img...
    <img...
</div>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unveil.js"></script>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")

    <script>
        (function ($) {   
            $('img').unveil();
        });
</script>
```

I also tried using

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('img').unveil();
  });
```

and got the errors:

```
jquery.unveil.js:13 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined
    at jquery.unveil.js:13
    at jquery.unveil.js:56


jquery-1.10.2.js:3062 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).unveil is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (UniMedEd:121)
    at fire (jquery-1.10.2.js:3062)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.10.2.js:3174)
    at Function.ready (jquery-1.10.2.js:447)
    at HTMLDocument.completed (jquery-1.10.2.js:118)
```

The second error i'm assuming even when document.ready is called the unveil.js file hasn't been loaded.

Any advice would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jquery.unveil.js:13 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined
    at jquery.unveil.js:13
    at jquery.unveil.js:56

L13:   $.fn.unveil = function(threshold, callback) {
L56:   })(window.jQuery || window.Zepto);
```

`jQuery` is undefined.

You should include jQuery before including any jQuery plugin:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unveil.js"></script>
<script>
    (function ($) {   
        $('img').unveil();
    });
</script>
```